# Fade Out News Ticker in Ruby on Rails. Trouble with example code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a fade-out news ticker. The code seems to be alright, but it's not working. For now I've put styling and script in html.erb (it's a ruby on rails partial)

```
<ol>
 <li class="divider">Company Pulse</li>
</ol>
  <ol id="scrollable" style="height:90px; overflow:hidden;">
    <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
       <li>
          <%= link_to "
            <div id=\"twitter_presence\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">
            <img src=\"#{tweet.user.profile_image_url}\" style=\"vertical-align:middle;\"/>
            <span style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">#{tweet.user.name}</span>
           </div>
            <span id=\"twitter_text\">
            <h3 style=\"text-align: center\">\" #{tweet.text} \"</h3>
            <h3 style=\"text-align:right\">#{tweet.created_at}</h3>
            </span>
          ".html_safe, 'employees/twitter' %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var aniSpd01 = 1000;
 var fadeSpd01 = 1000;

 $(function()
 {
    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = $('#scrollable li').length;
    $('#scrollable li:first').fadeIn(fadeSpd01);

    window.setInterval(function()
    {
        $('#scrollable li:eq(' + startIndex + ')').delay(fadeSpd01).fadeOut(fadeSpd01);
        startIndex++;
        $('#scrollable li:eq(' + startIndex + ')').fadeIn(fadeSpd01);

        if (endIndex == startIndex) startIndex = 0;
     }, aniSpd01);
 });
</script>
```

What could be wrong and how to fix that ?

Comment: People will need more info then "Its not working". Also, you should debug this on the frontend to workout what is wrong

Comment: it seems that jQuery is somehow conflicted. Error console gives out two ReferenceErrors: jQuerry is not defined and ReferenceError: $ is not defined.   //= require jquery.touchSwipe //= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery    are all in application.js

Comment: is that in order? jquery should be required first.

Comment: I tried several ordering strategies including jquery on top. still returns "jQuerry not defined" and the erros seems to come from jQuerry js itself: Timestamp: 02/12/2013 05:56:54 AM
Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Source File: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.js
Line: 781

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i rolled out my own js. can you try this?

```
var fadeOutSpeed = 1000,
    transitionSpeed = 1000,
    idx = 0;

function showNews() {
  $('#scrollable li').fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed, function() {
    $('#scrollable li:eql(' + idx + ')').fadeIn();
  });

  idx += 1;
  if (idx == $('#scrollable li').length) idx = 0;
  setTimeout('showNews()', transitionSpeed); 
}

function() { showNews() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There was a couple of things wrong here. This ticker script needs jQuery, and it is important that all javascripts in the application are loaded in order, through ./app/assets/javascripts/application.js

First thing to do is to put the script in a separate file at ./app/assets/javascripts  I named the file scroll.js

Next, go to application.js and add a line:

```
//= require scroll
```

It should go at the end of the require list, and after jquery,a jvnill suggested. After that, make sure the classes in the view are named accordingly. If the function does not work at this point, name it and add a line:

```
name();
```

at the end of the scroll.js file. (where name is the name of the function)